# Ionic Starter Template throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning after build

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

I have been tearing my hair out trying to get my windows machine to run an ionic android app in debug so that I can develop it on-going. I concluded that it must be something to do with my machine environment, despite having followed the relevant tutorials and checklists. I have therefore ignored my project and gone back to starting with a starter template to verify my environment.

I have tried setting up to use Android Studio, Visual Studio 2017 and from commandline. I have got farthest with the commandline and the starter template builds without errors (ionic cordova run android --device) and SAYS it has deployed to device or emulator but unfortunately nothing happens and all it provides me with is this error message :-

Package name: io.ionic.starter1
(node:12928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: C:\Users\Mike.summers\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
(node:12928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Anybody's help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these the only logs you get or do you get some more logs?

Comment: Hi Bharath, 
When running from commandline, I get the full output of the build (which is LONG) but it culminates in :-
"BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12s
48 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 47 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):"

Then the error listed above followed by ...

[OK] Your app has been deployed."

Comment: From the looks of it, it looks like your app was built and deployed. Regarding the error, have you checked https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-platform-add-android-exit-code-1-node-depreication-warnining/115996

Comment: Also what is your Cordova android platform version?

Comment: Ok the cordova version is 8.0.0

Comment: npm info :-
cli packages: 
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
    Node : v8.0.0
    npm  : 6.2.0
    OS   : Windows 8.1
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:
    backend : pro

Comment: It could be a problem with this version of Cordova. As per this post https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CB/issues/CB-13694?filter=allopenissues Try it with an older version of Cordova.

Comment: Oh ok - I will try and that and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, please try it.

Comment: OK I have reconfigured to have cordova 7.0.0 and with this output :-
Total time: 2.605 secs
Built the following apk(s):
...
ANDROID_HOME=<location>
JAVA_HOME=<location>
Skipping build...

Built the following apk(s):android-debug.apk
Using apk: android-debug.apk

Package name: io.ionic.starter
Error: adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --device (exit code        1).


adb devices
List of devices attached
42003c64e4d8b400        connecting

(Before build this said device not connecting)

Comment: The issue looks different. Could you get more logs. Maybe "ionic cordova build android --verbose" can help.

Comment: Ok i tried that command - no errors, says it deployed fine. When I change it to run instead of build I get successful messages, skipping build but this error :-
Package name: io.ionic.starter
Error: C:\Users\Mike.summers\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: C
ommand failed with exit code 1
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

[DEBUG] registerShutdownFunction process.exit/normal shutdown

Comment: It looks like an environment setup issue. Have you checked if your setup is as per https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html ?

Comment: I have but I will go through and check again and get back with anything I find

Comment: It all looks right yes

Comment: I mean the setup looks fine according to their instructions but still getting the error when I try to deploy to my device.